# Pass Unique PHP Variable to Javascript via Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is a continuation of my question here.

[Pass Text Input Variable to PHP for Div Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412506/pass-text-input-variable-to-php-for-div-loading)

The solution to that question looks like this:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goSearch(){
        $("#Moviesearchdiv").load("MovieSearch.php",$('#mySearch').serialize());
     }
</script>

<form action="JavaScript:goSearch()" method="POST" id="mySearch" >
    <input type="text" name="moviename">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" >
</form>

<div id="Moviesearchdiv"></div>
```

My MovieSearch.php looks something like this:

```
<?php
$themovie = $_POST["moviename"];
$myurl = "http://my-url-here.com/search/?q={$themovie}";

    $response = file_get_contents($myurl);
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
    $result=$result['movies'];

    $totality = count($result);

    for ($i = 0; $i <$totality; $i++) {
        $mymovietitle = $result[$i]['original_title'];
        $myposter = $result[$i]['poster_original'];
        $uniquemovieID = $result[$i]['movie_id'];
        echo "<li><img src={$myposter} >{$mymovietitle}</li>";
    }
?>
```

At the bottom of the php, within each found result, I want to have a button where I can add that movie to my collection. This is done with another API call that basically appends the 'movie-id' code to the end of the API url. So the bootom of the php above would look something like:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <$totality; $i++) {
        $mymovietitle = $result[$i]['original_title'];
        $myposter = $result[$i]['poster_original'];
        $uniquemovieID = $result[$i]['movie_id'];
        echo "<li><img src={$myposter} >{$mymovietitle}

        <form action='JavaScript:addMovie()' method='POST' id='{$uniquemovieID}' >
            <input type=hidden id=movieid  name=movieid value={$uniquemovieID }>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'  style='width: 50px;'>
        </form>

        </li>";
    }

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function addMovie()
    {
        $("#Moviesearchdiv").load("movieadd.php",$("#yourFormId2").serialize());  
    }
    </SCRIPT>
```

And finally the movieadd.php file looks like:

```
<?php
$themovieID = $_GET["movieid"];

$addurl = "http://my-api-url/movie.add/?identifier={$themovieID }";

$response = file_get_contents($addurl);
$result = json_decode($response, true);
$result=$result['success'];
echo $result;

if ($result$ == 'True') {
    echo "Movie was SUCCESSFULLY Added!";

} else {
    echo "Sorry, something went wrong...";
}


?>
```

Because the search return various movies, the form "id" for each movie needs to be unique. I would like to pass the PHP variable $uniquemovie to the JS function line replacing the #yourFormId2 value.

```
 $("#Moviesearchdiv").load("movieadd.php",$("#yourFormId2").serialize());
```

I hope someone can help... Any help advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Hernando

Comment: When you load MovieSearch.php you are sending moviename via GET there not POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the id itself to javascript.

```
<form action='JavaScript:addMovie('{$uniquemovieID}')' method='POST' id='{$uniquemovieID}' >
    <input type=hidden id=movieid  name=movieid value={$uniquemovieID }>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'  style='width: 50px;'>
</form>


<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function addMovie( movieId )
    {
        $("#Moviesearchdiv").load("movieadd.php",$("#" + movieId).serialize());  
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Thank you KNaito... I tried your code and did not have any luck, when inspecting the output, the form code was formatted as `<form action="JavaScript:addMovie(" tt1630029')'="" method="POST" id="tt1630029">` the tt1630029 is the correct movieID.

Comment: GOT IT TO WORK!!!! The correct syntax above is `<form action='JavaScript:addMovie(\"{$uniquemovieID}\")' method='POST' id='{$uniquemovieID}' >` Thank you very much KNaito, you did it!